# Can files be accessed on a network if Public folder sharing is turned off?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

I was recently trying to transfer some files from my "Downloads" folder on my Win 10 laptop to my android phone using "ES file explorer". I followed instructions from here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83427/can-not-connect-to-pc-from-android-via-es-explorer which recommended to turn off "password protected sharing" under "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings". My laptop is password protected. I was then able to transfer files to and from the laptop. My question is, could anyone else on the network have accessed my folder? I have also noticed that "Public folder sharing" was turned off. So if "Public folder sharing" was turned off, how could my android phone have accessed the files in the "downloads" folder? I am not very familiar with networking and am a little concerned if any of my data has been compromised. I have now re-enabled "password protected sharing" and when I tried logging in using ES  file explorer it asked me for the computer username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by disabling Password Protected Sharing, you are effectively adding guest access to your shares.

per MS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772566(v=ws.10).aspx)

> Password-protected sharing. This option is only available on computers that are not joined to a domain. Turning on this option restricts access to users who have a user account and password on this computer. When this option is turned off, any user on the network can access files and folders that are shared to "Everyone."

So Password Protected Sharing helps you configure share permissions, and does not automatically allow guest/anonymous access.

Public Folder Sharing is a specific feature in Windows, that automatically shares the Public profile (usually at c:\users\public) for all computers and users that can access the PC.

From the same document:

> Public folder sharing. Turning on this option shares the c:\users\public folder as \computername\public. You have the option to share the folder with read permissions only, or with full read/write permissions. If you want to change the permissions assigned to this folder, you can use the Advanced Sharing feature (available on the Sharing tab of every folder) to adjust the users and groups to whom permissions are given. Turning on public folder sharing automatically enables file sharing.

Personally, I want people to use passwords on my workgroup so, I always

- disable homegroups
- enable password protected sharing
- disable public sharing
- use advanced sharing to create each of my shares.

I set my share permissions to Everyone => Full Control, and then lock down the filesystem permissions to allow only the specific users that should see the content. This is recommended by MS, because if you have content on another disk shared, and rebuild the system, your filesystem permissions on the shared items will remain exactly as they were. if you put all your access control logic in the share permissions however, those get lost when the OS instance is replaced with the new build.

Comment: So what you're saying is that inspite of "Public folder sharing" being off, disabling "Password Protected Sharing" would still give access to the "Public" folder on the network? 

By the way the path of the folder which I had shared was "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads" not "c:\users\public". Does sharing any folder make it a "Public" folder?

Also how do I check if the folder is still share or is public?

Comment: I don't believe the public folder is shared at all if public folder sharing is disabled; sharing the public folder is what that feature does, but all your shares will accept guest/anon users if password protected sharing is off. Basically the two settings have little or nothing to do with each other. one creates a public share, the other makes all your shares available to all users.

Comment: So simply put, the "public" folder and the "shared" folder are two different things, am I correct? So does it mean the data in my "C:\Users\<username>\Downloads" folder, for which I had disabled "Password Protected Sharing", has been compromised? Is there any way to check this?

Comment: that is correct. It means that it was accessible, but doesn't imply anything more at this time. As for comprimise, I'm not sure how you might tell objectively, because the security log events for login wouldn't be recorded the way they should for a logging in user. usually I'd look for event ID 4624 in the sec log, but I don;t think that will work for guest users. worth a look though.

Comment: Thanks. How do I find this event ID 4624?

Comment: And how can I tell what computers are logged into the network? In the earlier versions of windows we could see the list of computers in the network by going to "Network neighbourhood". How do I do so in windows 10?

Comment: well, you see these events in the event viewer under "Security Log", but I don't think any entries will have been logged because you turned off login by disabling password protected sharing. as for network neighborhood, look in explorer on the right pane for "network".  beyond that, This is getting  well beyond the scope of the original question. I encourage you to create a new question specific to your subsequent queries.